# Running the server.js in a specific folder

Tags: node.js

I tried to run my server.js

like `C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs>node server.js`

But when I tried to run like

```
C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\Team_share>node server.js
```

I get

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please Advice

Comment: Did you try running it like this: node "C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodjs\Team_share\server.js" ?

Comment: Add 'C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs' to your environement variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd.exe then type:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs"
```

*that command will add `C:\Users\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs` to PATH environment variable. You can do it only one time, it will store in your registry permanently*

then close the command window, then open it again then run:

```
cd C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\Team_share
node server.js
```